# how to print a message multiple times on multiple different lines?

Tags: python

for starters im new to python and not really good at this kind of thing so dont crusify me ive had bad experiences on reddit.

But, Im able to get user input to repeat the string x amount of times but i cant get it to repeat on different lines.

ive tried \n multiple times (the only thing ive used) in multiple different ways but i just get invalid syntax but i havent really tried to change the base code much.

```
age = int(input("how old are you?: "))

agedifference = 100 - age

print ("you will be 100 in",agedifference,"years") * int(input("pick a number: "))
```

so basically i need the user to pick a number for example 4 then repeat the phrase 4 times on 4 different lines.

if you can give a solution with an in depth explanation i would greatly appreciate it (no such thing as to in depth im noob)

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to repeat blocks of code

Comment: Please add a sample input and desired output for more clarity.

Comment: *Hint:* `\n` is a newline character which helps you add line breaks. Now, think where you should add `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming you are on python3):

```
age = int(input("how old are you?: "))

agedifference = 100 - age

print(f"you will be 100 in {agedifference} years\n" * int(input("pick a number: ")))
```

For python2:

```
age = int(input("how old are you?: "))

agedifference = 100 - age

print("you will be 100 in {} years\n".format(agedifference) * int(input("pick a number: ")))
```

Comment: this was very helpful also i realized that alot of what i tried should have worked but since i typed in the terminal "python example.py" it was running in python 2.7 instead of 3.7. found the solution "python3 example.py" rip

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of solutions for what you want:

The classic for loop:

```
for _ in range(num):
    print(f"you will be 100 in {agedifference} years")
```

In python, a print ends the line by default, you can change this behaviour by modifying the `end` parameter of the function.

The more pythonic one liner:

```
print('\n'.join([f"you will be 100 in {agedifference} years"] * num))
```

This one takes advantage of multiple python features:

- `str.join(iterable)` will create a string by concatenating all elements contained in `iterable` and join them by adding the `str` in between.
- `list * int` repeats all elements in the `list` `int` times.
- f-string are one of the many ways to insert variables in string without having to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this as well:

You ask the user to input age and you calculate the agedifference.

Then you ask the user to input the times it has to repeat.

Then use a `for` loop for looping the output the number of times given by the user.

```
age = int(input("how old are you?: "))

agedifference = 100 - age

times = int(input("pick a number: "))

for i in range(0,times):
    print ("you will be 100 in",agedifference,"years")
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens with your code is that you are multiplying the return value of `print()`, which is `None`, by the number input by the user. Instead, you should repeat the string which is passed in the `print()` function.

When calling the `print()` function, here, make sure the string you print ends with a `\n`. Also, my example needs Python >= 3.6 because of the way the string is formatted (with the 'f' before the string), it is called [literal string interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Finally, to get rid of the last line return which prints an empty line, add the argument `end=''` to the call to `print()` (because this character is already in the string your print).

```
age = int(input("how old are you?: "))

age_difference = 100 - age

repetitions = int(input("pick a number: "))

print(f"you will be 100 in {age_difference} years\n" * repetitions, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a beginner. I know it's lengthy but easy to read and understand.

You have also written the code correct but you should have added extra open bracket and close it. It will be more clean if you have do the same with Formatted Strings.

`````
age_difference=100-age
message=(f'''you will be 100 in {age_difference} years''') 
print(message)
number=int(input('pick a number: '))
print(f''' {(message)}''' * number)  ````
`````